# Wrong ECDSA OID in iText7?

Tags: itext7

I created a signed pdf using iText7 with an EC key. The PDF is verified successfully in Adobe Acrobat reader without complaint. However, when checked with ETSI conformance checker, the tool complains 'Unknown signature type requested: SHA256With1.2.840.10045.2.1'

The SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier in the Cryptographic Messaging Syntax (CMS) is shown as ecPublicKey instead of an ECDSA with SHA256

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.2.1 ecPublicKey (ANSI X9.62 public key type)
            NULL
```

Checking the iText7 source code shows that [PdfPKCS7](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/sign/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/signatures/PdfPKCS7.java) uses [SecurityIDs](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/sign/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/signatures/SecurityIDs.java) which defines ECDSA OID as the following:

```
public static final String ID_ECDSA = "1.2.840.10045.2.1";
```

May I know if this is a bug where the code should be changed to use the following ECDSA signature algorithm OIDs?

```
public static final String ID_ECDSA_SHA224 = "1.2.840.10045.4.3.1";
public static final String ID_ECDSA_SHA256 = "1.2.840.10045.4.3.2";
public static final String ID_ECDSA_SHA384 = "1.2.840.10045.4.3.3";
public static final String ID_ECDSA_SHA512 = "1.2.840.10045.4.3.4";
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is a known issue. To generate ECDSA signatures with iText up to at least the current 7.2.2 please use an `IExternalSignatureContainer` with `PdfSigner.signExternalContainer` instead of an `IExternalSignature` with `PdfSigner.signDetached`. For some backgrounds read [Which Interface to Use](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signing-with-itext-7/part-i-overview-and-simple-cases#PartIOverviewandSimpleCases-WhichInterfacetoUse) of the iText knowledge base article [Digital Signing with iText 7](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signing-with-itext-7).

Comment: Thank you. This issue is fixed by implementing IExternalSignatureContainer.